# Laravel Echo Authentication for both normal Web and API middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-echo

I have a Laravel application build with `Laravel Echo` with private channels via Pusher. This is working, because I authenticate my users via the normal way (no API-tokens).

Then I have a NuxtJS application, with authentication via a Bearer-token. So for that application I use the following code:

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: "pusher",
  key: "1234567",
  forceTLS: true,
  authEndpoint: "https://mywebsite.com/broadcasting/auth",
  auth: {
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + "foobar",
      Accept: "application/json",
    },
  },
});
```

The problem is, that I cannot authenticate my Users in the NuxtJS app.. because it uses a different way to Authenticate them.

In the `BroadcastServiceProvider` of the Laravel application, I have this `Broadcast::routes();`. This is the way it works in the Laravel Application.

When I change it to this: `Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:api', 'auth']]);`.. it works in the NuxtJS application, but NOT in the Laravel application anymore.

Is there a way I can authenticate my broadcasting endpoint on both the regular authentication way as the bearer-token way?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
if (request()->hasHeader('authorization')) {
   Broadcast::routes(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => ['auth:api']]);
} else {
   Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']]);
}
```

Also I got 403 error in api `Broadcast::auth($request)` method with the same config as yours in spite of the request passed throw `auth:api` middleware. Then in Echo config I try custom authorize method and it worked. My Echo config:

```
    window.Echo = new Echo({
      broadcaster: 'pusher',
      key: 123456,
      wsHost: window.location.hostname,
      wsPort: 6101,
      forceTLS: false,
      authorizer: (channel, options) => {
        return {
          authorize: (socketId, callback) => {
            fetch(environment.apiDomain + '/broadcasting/auth', {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + cookieService.get('token')
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({
                socket_id: socketId,
                channel_name: channel.name
              })
            })
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(data => {
                callback(false, data);
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                callback(true, error);
              });
          }
        };
      },
    });
```

Comment: Can you please explain why  prefix '/api' necessary?